# WCF REST and asp.net and debugging

Tags: wcf, iis-7, wcf-binding

I have an asp.net 4 application that hosts a WCF REST service via WebServiceHost...

```
WebServiceHostFactory factory = new WebServiceHostFactory();
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("mss", factory, typeof(ModuleStorage)));
```

My application has a custom authentication module and requires IIS Anonymous access.  I also have Windows Integrated so that I can debug my application.

The issue I am having is the WebHttpBinding created by the WebServiceHost does not support having two authentication methods enabled in IIS.  I can turn off Win. Auth. and it works but I can not debug.

So my question is... Can I enable WebHttpBinding to support both or can I somehow enable debugging without Win. Auth.

This service must be hosted as part of the application and I need a way to debug it.

Comment: Are you about to attach the the iis process with out expecting visual studio to auto attach?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.  I am starting the application in debug mode so yes I want VS to auto attach to the worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ASP.NET Web API.  I have to say so far I am a big fan!

http://www.asp.net/web-api

Answer (score 3):

Try debugging WCF REST Service using Fiddler, see the following links for more informations :
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/213007/Debug-WCF-REST-Service

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you are trying to debug.  You could always trace the WCF service using SvcTraceViewer.  [Here is the config](http://davintryon.blogspot.com/2012/03/wcf-tracing-raw-soap-xml.html) you can use on the server.